# Mathematical expression for a function based on finding integer elements

Tags: optimization

Suppose we are given a binary vector $\mathbf{v}=[1,0 ,0, 1 ,0]$. A function $O(\mathbf{v})$ in a pseudo-code sense is defined as
$$
O(\mathbf{v})=Sum(20^*(\mathbf{v}==1)+10^*(\mathbf{v}==0)).
$$
which equals to
$$
O(\mathbf{v})=20+10+10+20+10.
$$
One can write the corresponding mathematical expression for $O(\mathbf{v})$ as
$$
\mathbf{v}'=20\mathbf{v}+10(1-\mathbf{v})$$
$$
O(\mathbf{v})=\sum_{i} \mathbf{v}'(i)
$$
This is doable for a binary case. My question is whether it is possible to do a similar thing if $\mathbf{v}(i)\in\{0,1,2,3\}$. Specifically, assume

$$
O(\mathbf{v})=Sum(40^*(\mathbf{v}==3)+30^*(\mathbf{v}==2)+20^*(\mathbf{v}==1)+10^*(\mathbf{v}==0)).
$$
How can I write the above $O(\mathbf{v})$ in a mathematical form.

Comment: You have already answered your question: your form for $O$ is already "mathematical."  Could you please, then, explain what you are looking for?  Some algebraic function that agrees with $O,$ perhaps?  If so, note (for instance) that $(v-3)(v-1)(v-0)$ is a nonzero multiple of "$v==2$" and go on from there.  But what statistical application would this mathematical manipulation help you with?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was indeed looking for expressions like $(\mathbf{v}-3)(\mathbf{v}-1)(\mathbf{v}-0)$, but I could not think of any before your comment.